# Стороннее консольное приложение - часть неконсольной программы?

Tags: delphi, exe

Можно ли в Delphi использовать сторонее консольное приложение, как часть не консольной программы?

То есть у меня есть обычная программа -- ping.exe. (стандартная, которая в system32)
Можно ли мне как-нибудь программно подключать её в свою программу и выполнять какие-либо действия с её участием? То есть как будто ввести в консоли ping.exe 172.0.0.1 и будет выдан результат в какой-нибудь Memo?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Откройте для себя замечательный сайтик [delphisources.ru](http://www.delphisources.ru/pages/faq/os_hardware.html). По ссылке куча примеров по работе с программами, в разделе "DOS и Консоль" смотрите первый же пункт - "CreateProcess, который возвращает консольный вывод".

Answer (score 2):

То, что вы хотите - функция system() в СИ. Полного аналога в Делфи нету. Как было замечено выше, вам могут помочь функции:

- WinExec() // устарела
- CreateProcess()
- ShellExecute()